# Android calendar timetable

Tags: android, calendar

I want to develop a student's timetable for an android application. For this I need to have a calendar to know the day and to check whether the day is a weekday(since saturday and sunday doesnt need a timetable).Can I get the calendar on the phone to do this or do I have to come up with one of my own?
Any help is much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimeUtils.html are also worth looking into in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html 
The java Calender API provide everything that you describe above.